# Automorphisms for direct products of finite commutative nilpotent rings.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Let $(R, +, \cdot)$ be an associative commutative nilpotent ring of cardinality $2^n$ such that
$$
r^2 = 0,
$$
for every $r\in R$. Also $(V, +)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  Let $\operatorname{Aut}(R)$ be a group of ring automorphisms. That is a group of bijective maps $\phi: R\to R $ such taht for every $r,s\in R$ and $*\in \{+, \cdot\}$
$$
\phi(r*s) = \phi(r)*\phi(s).
$$

I want to know how the group of automorphisms for the direct product
$$
\underbrace{R\oplus R \oplus\ldots \oplus R}_{k}
$$
is structured.

Of course it contains trivial diagonal automorphisms of the form
$$
\Phi(r_1, \ldots, r_k) = (\phi_1(r_1), \ldots, \phi_k(r_k)),
$$
where $\phi_i\in \operatorname{Aut}(R)$.
Also there are automorphisms acting as permutations, that is for $\sigma \in S_k$
$$
\Psi_{\sigma}(r_1, \ldots, r_k) = (r_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, r_{\sigma(k)}).
$$

But what about more subtle maps? It is interesting how the whole group of automorphisms for $\underbrace{R\oplus R \oplus\ldots \oplus R}_{k}$ is structured.

My attempts. I'm trying to start from investigation for
$$
R\oplus R
$$
automorphisms. Let $\phi$ be such automorphism. Then since $\phi$ is $+$ automorphism there exist $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \operatorname{Hom_+}(R,R)$ such that
$$
\phi(x,y) = (\alpha(x) + \beta(y), \gamma(x) + \delta(y)),
$$
(this is usual matrix product). Then since $\phi$ preserves multiplication we have
$$
\phi(xz,yt) = \phi(x,y)\phi(z,t),
$$
for arbitrary $x,y,z,t\in R$.
Combining this with the above equality and using the fact that we working in vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ we can obtain that $\alpha,\beta, \gamma, \delta$ are also multiplicative homomorphisms. Then $\phi$ is automorphism if and only if for all $x,y,z,t\in R$ we have
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\alpha(x)\beta(t) = \beta(y)\alpha(z) \\
\gamma(x)\delta(t) = \delta(y)\gamma(z) \\
\end{array}
$$
and $\phi$ is bijection.
Next, I'm stuck.

Comment: Well, it also contains permutations $\Phi(r_1,\dots,r_k) = (r_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, r_{\sigma(k)})$

Comment: @lisyarus, thank you very much. But this is also trivial case. I will correct my question. I want to know the structure of the whole group.

Comment: Sure, I'm not claiming that's the whole group :)

Comment: FWIW The user Statistics Tutorial is a bot. I haven't read what they've written in their answer here but I'd be very, very wary of trusting anything it says

Comment: @FShrike, thank you very much.

Comment: @MikhailGoltvanitsa Do you know that there exists an automorphism that isn't just a composition of a diagonal and a permutation?  My first thought was that you'd use some construction similar to semi-direct products. I'm not sure if it works though.

Comment: are you saying that R is a vector space over F2?

Comment: @Martin, yes, R is an algebra over $GF(2)$ of dimension $n$.